# What is the meaning of "can I help this"?

Tags: meaning, british-english

What is the meaning of "can I help this?" in this passage from Dickens' *The Old Curiosity Shop*? Is it "can I avoid this?"

> Now, whether she was in her laughing joy, or in her crying one, the Marchioness could not help turning to the visitors with an appealing look, which seemed to say, 'You see this fellow—***can I help this?***'—and they, being thus made, as it were, parties to the scene, as regularly answered by another look, 'No. Certainly not.' This dumb-show, taking place during the whole time of the invalid's breakfast, and the invalid himself, pale and emaciated, performing no small part in the same, it may be fairly questioned whether at any meal, where no word, good or bad, was spoken from beginning to end, so much was expressed by gestures in themselves so slight and unimportant.

Answer (score 1):

As the recovering Dick Swiveller eats his first breakfast, 'The Marchioness' varies between laughing with joy and weeping with emotion; she looks at the visitors as if to say, "I can't help being like this, can I?"